# Rounded black box on each page in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm working on a very simple beamer theme for my presentations based on the default beamer template. I would like to make it a bit like a transparent handout with the white background and a bold rounded box (of the constant size) around the text contained within the frame (which would define the margins for the inner text and have some distance from the page borders).

I understand I should put this probably into the *background* or *background canvas* template but I'm quite stuck on how to actually define that frame (using which package for example).

Could somebody point me to such a package or give a tip for the solution? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I would like to avoid creating an external image file and including it on each page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some like that?

```
% Basically plagiarized from ...(lost reference, edit yourself) 
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw [color=black!60!magenta,inner color=black!95!orange, outer color=black!80!blue, line width=1mm,rounded corners]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (0.5cm,-0.5cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-0.5cm,0.5cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\centering\Huge\bfseries\color{yellow}Sample text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. That works perfectly. It took me some time to google out PGF and TikZ. I don't know how I could live without that before :)